# clear out class variable in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class and created its instances `a` and `b`. I think both instances points same address.

For example,

```
class Foo:
    counter = 0
    def increment():
        counter += 1

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
for i in range(10):
    a.increment()
    b.increment()
    aa = a.counter
    bb = b.counter
    print(aa)
    print(bb)
```

I expected that `aa = 10` and `bb = 10`. However `bb = 20` at this point. What am I missing?

Comment: Your counter variable is a class variable instead of an instance variable. You would access instance variables using self. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: your code doesn't work: `increment` isn't a class method and `counter` should be `self.counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to make the counter specific to each instance you should make it an instance variable and initialize it in the `__init__` method instead:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
```

Comment: I think we can call that a classic duplicate and avoid answering this.